# How to make indentation smaller in qt tooltips with html listing format?

Tags: html, c++, qt

I am using html listing format to write tooltips in Qt as below.

```
widget->setTooltip(tr("<ul><li>First sentence</li></ul>"));
```

I found the indentation is too large. How can I set the indentation smaller?

Answer (score 8):

Quite some time has passed but here is some information that might help you.

After doing some digging and also because Qt Designer was constantly replacing and screwing up my HTML that I wanted to use for my tooltip I looked closely and found the following:

```
<ul style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; -qt-list-indent:X;">
...
</ul>
```

with `X` being some number >= 0 (0 is basically the equivalent of left alignment). For the `<li/>` etc. you can use `-qt-block-indent:X` inside the `style` parameter of the tag.

That sad I was unable to make the indention less than it already is without loosing the bullet points. If you set `-qt-list-indent:0` then you have (as mentioned above) a text on several lines with left alignment. If you set `-qt-list-indent:1` you get the default behaviour which is what you want to change. I'm not much of a CSS/HTML person and also the Qt documentation is extremely lacking on this topic but I do believe decimal values are not allowed hence 1 is as low as you can get with indention. I've tried decimal values such as 0.5 or similar but I get the same result as if 1 was entered which leads to the conclusion that only integers can be used, it's a bug or this applies only to values between 0 and 1.

[Here](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/demos/textedit/example.html) is an example of some HTML using this indention.

Comment: Thanks, I was facing the same problem. I believe that only "0" and "1" values are accepted because it is a boolean : "0" means "no indentation" and "1" means "use indentation".

Comment: Hi. I haven't actually tried using values between 0 and 1. Did you test it? If you have solid proof I will definitely edit my post.

Comment: No, I don't have a solid proof, since it's poorly documented. I could try to track the usage of this value in the code, but it's very deep in the Qt's code. After some try, it appears the only accepted values are "0" and "not 0", this is why I think this value is used as a boolean.

Comment: So  you tried let's say 0.5 and you got the same result as if you have written 0 or 1? That's a proof enough alright. :) Especially since there is actually no documentation on this and as you wrote you have to dig deep into Qt's source code.

Comment: Thanks for this useful post, I've been struggling about it for ages. BTW, what I've found is that using a 0 basically disables Qt's indentation and then you can use the `margin-...` properties.

Comment: I turned it around and used negative margins, which also worked(rich text edit in QML):

`<ul style="margin-left:-20px"><li>item</li></ul>`

Comment: There is a lot of new info I can see. Does someone want to post an answer (what @cbuchart and TomDeblauwe posted seems to sum it up plus the boolean type from Aurelien) so that I can "close" this question?

Comment: This one works for me: `style="margin-left:15px; -qt-list-indent: 0;"`

Comment: If the answer would involve the hints for work-around given in comments it would be worth an accepted checkmark, IMHO. Even as it is it was valuable to fix the not-so-nice default look of rich-texts with lists in my `QTextEdit`.

Answer (score 2):

[esmirnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475821)'s answer, posted as a [comment on Dec 5. 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000206/how-to-make-indentation-smaller-in-qt-tooltips-with-html-listing-format/72068873#comment94127933_35259533), worked for me.

> ```
> style="margin-left:15px; -qt-list-indent: 0;"
> ```